# Pluma/Gedit REMOVE languages

Tags: gedit, syntax, pluma

I like to remove most of the languages from the pluma/gedit menues, where they show up.

It's great that the editors support so many languages. But most of them I never use. So they are only in the way and I don't have enough time, scrolling the whole day to my entries.

They show up in the language type selection of the status bar, in the plugin dialog (for which kind of document), in the snippet configuration and maybe more spaces. Is it possible to edit some configuration file, to get rid of most of them?

Or do I have to get the sources, and fix the issues there? More than 90% of the time, I only use 3 or 4 languages or plain text. I guess other users have a similar usage pattern, of course with different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pluma uses GTKSourceView to highlight languages.

The package for its common files, which is typically something like libgtksourceview-3.0-common contains the language definitions which are typically stored as XML files in /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/

What I've done just gooling this issue now and not finding a solution, is create a directory inside there called All/ and moved all the files in there to the /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/All/ and I'm just going to move the ones I use back into /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/ which will make only those show up in the menu.

This however doesn't apply only to Pluma, but anything which uses GTKSourceView.

On my system there are 135 files in this directory and you need to leave the following 4 in there for any highlighting to work:

def.lang, language2.rng, language.dtd, and language.rng

I now have only 24 other .lang files in there for all languages I will conceivably view or code in:

automake awk chdr c cmake cpphdr cpp css csv dosbatch html json julia lua makefile pascal perl php python3 python sh tcl xml yaml

and these are now all that show up in the pluma menu.

Note: the name of the file isn't necessarily what shows up in the menu such as files like chdr.lang, cpp.lang, cpphdr.lang, for example which show as C/ObjC Header, C++, C++ Header respectively.

This is not an /ideal/ solution as it can be overwritten by updates to the gtksourceview-common package, but its the only way I see to do it other than modifying the source code of pluma or gtksourceview and recompiling.